# Using useRef on imported Icons from React Icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im just trying to set a Ref to an imported React Icon. But for some reason it does not work. I receive the following error message:

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')"

Is there a special way to refer to an imported file?

```html
import React from 'react'
import { useRef } from 'react'


import {HiPlus, HiThumbDown, HiThumbUp, HiArrowNarrowRight} from "react-icons/hi"

function Card(props) {

    var addToFavRef = useRef()
    var thumbUpRef = useRef()
    var thumbDownRef = useRef()

function addToFavorites(){

        addToFavRef.current.style.color = "orange"
        addToFavRef.current.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)"
}
    
function thumbUp(){
        thumbDownRef.current.style.color = "grey"
        thumbDownRef.current.style.opacity = "50%"
}

return (
<>
  <HiPlus className="cardPlusIcon" ref={addToFavRef}></HiPlus>
  <HiThumbUp className="cardThumbUp" ref={thumbUpRef} onClick={thumbUp}></HiThumbUp>
  <HiThumbDown className="cardThumbDown" ref={thumbDownRef} onClick={thumpDown}></HiThumbDown>
</>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Here's the message:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be using `useRef` for this. You should import a CSS file and then set the `className` on the elements.

Comment: But im using useRef like that on other HTML Elements within other components and it workes fine. Its just the problem with the Icons. I would like to use useRef for that if its possible in any way.

Comment: I assume its because they are components consisting of svg elements and not elements on their own. So there is no reference to the svg element directly.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: Is there something fundamentally wrong with it? This is what useRef is made for, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a ref attached to the react icons svg. If you use typescript you can see the error when you try to add one.

If you really must access the dom node then you can wrap each icon in a div or span and attach a ref to that and then you can access it by the child node like `ref.current.childNodes[0]`

But it makes no sense in your case to do this if you are going to set the style just set it. There is no reason to access the dom node here. You can do so by adding classes or just setting the style directly.

```
import {HiPlus, HiThumbDown, HiThumbUp, HiArrowNarrowRight} from "react-icons/hi"
import {useState} from 'react'

const thumbsUpStyle = {
  color: 'orange',
  transform: 'rotate(45deg)'
}

const thumbsDownStyle = {
  color: 'orange',
  transform: 'rotate(-45deg)'
}

const favoritesStyle = {
  color: 'grey',
  opacity: '50%'
}

export default function Card() {
  const [thumbs, setThumbs] = useState('')
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <HiPlus onClick={() => setFavorites(true)} style={favorites && favoritesStyle}/>
      <HiThumbUp onClick={() => setThumbs('up')} style={thumbs === 'up' && thumbsUpStyle}/>
      <HiThumbDown  onClick={() => setThumbs('down')} style={thumbs === 'down' && thumbsDownStyle}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or just add a corresponding class and style that class in your stylesheet

```
import {HiPlus, HiThumbDown, HiThumbUp, HiArrowNarrowRight} from "react-icons/hi"
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function Card() {
  const [thumbs, setThumbs] = useState('')
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <HiPlus onClick={() => setFavorites(true)} className={favorites && 'favorites-class'}/>
      <HiThumbUp onClick={() => setThumbs('up')} className={thumbs === 'up' && 'thumbs-up-class'}/>
      <HiThumbDown  onClick={() => setThumbs('down')} className={thumbs === 'down' && 'thumbs-down-class'}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```